# Getting japanees character in response and show in android app

Tags: android, json, retrofit2

I am developing a app in which name is coming in japanees language and I need to show that name in my android app so how can I do it?

I am using retrofit library for getting response.

Below is the json format:

```
 {
  "location": {
    "lat": 35.89641599999999,
    "lng": 139.632189
  },
  "id": "133d09371c89ada803fd39fe4ddcbd777ff01a8a",
  "name": "東横INNさいたま新都心"
},
```

Comment: What the problem you getting?

Comment: have you try this ?